# Change the subject and header of the email to be sent to the product author

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My website has a system where users can add their own products and publish them when the admin agrees, so when the product is purchased I want the user/product owner to get an email notification that the product has been checkout. For now I can send email notifications to buyers and product owners. But the email that was sent has the same fields.

So I want to distinguish the contents of the subject and header of the email sent to the product owner so that it is not the same as that sent to the buyer/customer.
Is there any code I can put in function.php or the plugin snippet to build the feature?

Thank you, regards.

**Here is my code for send product author checkout process email**

```
    function ajout_proprietaire_mail_commande_wc ($recipient, $order) {
        $order = new WC_Order($order->id);
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) 
        {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        }
        $product_author_id=get_post_field('post_author', $product_id);
        $product_author = get_userdata( $product_author_id );
        $productAuthorEmail = $product_author->user_email;
        $recipient = $recipient . ', ' . $productAuthorEmail;
        return $recipient;
    }
```

**Here is my try code for send email with different header and send it to product author, but doesnt work**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_subject_customer_completed_order', 'change_admin_email_subject', 10, 2);
function change_admin_email_subject( $subject,$recipient, $order ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    foreach ( $order_data as $data_buyer ) {
        $product_id = $data_buyer['product_id'];
        $order_billing_email = $data_buyer['billing']['email'];
    }
    if ($recipient =! $order_billing_email) {
        $subject = sprintf( 'ini pelelang');        
    }
    else {
        return $subject;
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Wordpress : V.5.9
Woocommerce : 6.1.1

Comment: Your current code assumes that an order always consists of only 1 product, is this the case?  and the e-mail notification will only be sent when the status of the order changes to 'completed', is that the intention?

Comment: The problem is not that the order always consists of only 1 product, the problem is how to change the header and subject of the email that will be sent to the product author?
Because the email sent to the product author is an email that the checkout process has completed, which by default is sent to the customer who ordered the product.
 
In conclusion, the customer and product received an email, the checkout process was complete. However, I want the email sent to the product author to have a different header and subject.

Comment: 1. Your current code assumes that an order always consists of only 1 product, is this the case? *That's not the problem.
2. The e-mail notification will only be sent when the status of the order changes to 'completed', is that the intention? *Yes.

Comment: _"That's not the problem"_ - Let me put my questions differently. **1)** If an order consists of several products, is the author for all these products the same or can it be different? because if so, who should the email be sent to? **2)** When the checkout process is completed, an order will not automatically have the status 'completed' but generally a status such as 'on hold', 'pending payment' or 'processing'. So the emails that are sent at that time are separate from the order status 'completed'.

Comment: **1)** Product authors can be different, so buyers can buy products from several different product authors.
**2)** The email sent is an order status email, because the email will be a report for the product author if the product has just been purchased.